# Derivative of a Multivariate Heaviside unit step function

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

Recently in an article, I stumble upon what seems to be a sum of multivariate heaviside functions:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\theta)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^nH(\theta_i\leq\theta,\rho_i\geq\rho_{z:n})
\end{equation}
where $\rho_{z:n}$ is the z-th order statistic. On the same article, they proceed to evaluate the integral over d$\Gamma(\theta)$.
What is the expression for d$\Gamma(\theta)$?

I suppose it should involve $\delta(\theta-\theta_i)$ but I haven't arrived any further.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have figured out the answer. Given that it must apply that:
\begin{equation}
H(x,y)=H(x)H(y)
\end{equation}
The result is simply:
\begin{equation}
\text{d}\Gamma(\theta)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta(\theta-\theta_i)H(\rho_i-\rho_{z:n})\text{d}\theta
\end{equation}